# d3.js trying to export data string

Tags: java, d3.js, nodes, parent, children

I wonder if any D3 gurus can help.

I'm trying to put together a heirachy staff graphic - with some admin functions - this I have done, clicking on various nodes return user details and so on...

I have used this code [as my base](https://medium.com/code-wave/building-a-tree-with-d3-537d43cbd9ab)

I'm using MS SQL as a datasource and I have managed to take a table and create the data for the D3 tree.

**Thats all the good news...**

What I'm now trying to do is have a "save button" so that when someone has added, removed, edited or created new nodes they can press a button and it saves the data back.

I dont mind writing the code, but the thing I'm banging my head against is stepping through each node and grabbing the child/and or/parent.

I've searched the web and found a few things, but they dont seem to work or give [object object] results.

So far I have this, which steps through all the nodes and returns thier Id's:

```
d3.selectAll('g.node')  
.each(function(p) {

    alert(p.id + " " + p.children )
    });

};
```

This returns me the node ID and tries to get the children associated.

For example, Node 1 is

1 [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

It would be perfect if it were

1 2,5,7,8,10

Any help or pointers would be very very very much appreciated.

Comment: So.... you just want a simple map from children to their id? `p.children.map(function(c) { return c.id; });`

Comment: Thank you Coderino - I've tried to implement this on the button.                  
  Getting: function map() { [native code] } as a result. It clearly sees the 3 levels which is far more than I managed to get from this.

Comment: IT WORKS (In caps as this has taken me ages to get this far) Many many thanks Coderino !!